# MYSQL Query double JOIN

Tags: php, mysql, sql, inner-join, semi-join

This is my query:

```
SELECT count(*) AS COUNT
FROM `psttodo-in` p
INNER JOIN `deelgebied` d 
    ON d.`Segmentcode` = p.`Segment No_ PST`
    AND d.`Deelgebied` = p.`Deelgebied`
INNER JOIN m2m 
    ON m2m.`deelgebied` = d.`deelgebiedID`
WHERE 
    p.`Segment No_ PST` = 'PSS1400146'
    AND p.`Deelgebied` = 2
ORDER BY `afgewerkt tablet datum`
```

Now when I check my table `psttodo-in` in Sequal Pro and I select the rows where `Segment No_ PST = PSS1400146` and `Deelgebied = 2` I count `84`. But when I run the query I get a result of `252`. What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE**:

My table structure :

```
table psttodo-in:
    PK No_
    Hostess Code
    Segment No_
    FK Deelgebied
    ....

table deelgebied
    Segmentcode
    Deelgebied
    map
    DeelgebiedID
    pst-active

table m2m
    PK m2mID
    FK deelgebied
    FK psthostess
```

Comment: Multiple records from other tables match your `ON`-clauses.

Comment: I don't get it... How can I fix this?

Comment: That depends on your table structure, please share them in order to provide enough information so we can analyze the problem.

Comment: find a better way to filter rows from joined table, add extra clause to identify unique records.

Comment: your joins will return ALL matching records in both tables. you might have only 84 records in psttodo-in, but obviously there's multiple matching records in the OTHER tables. e.g. if pstoddo-in has a record `(a,b)`, and the joins bring back `(a,b,1)` and `(a,b,2)`, your pstoddo-in count is one, but you still have two records.

Comment: I updated my begin post with table structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's always exactly one row in `d` for each row in `p`, because of the foreign key reference.

But there may be multiple rows in `m2m` for each or in `d`. In fact, since 252 is 84 * 3, I would guess that there are three rows in `m2m` for each `d` (or at least the average is three). Thus in the joined result set, the rows are tripled, with distinct rows from `m2m` but the rows from `p` and `d` are repeated.

There are a couple of ways to fix this:

**Count each `p` only once**

We know that in the repeated rows, the values from `p` and `d` are repeated. So pick a column that is known to be unique in either `p` or `d`, and count only the distinct values in it. We can't pick `d` because those might be chosen more than once legitimately, if two different `p` entries reference the same `d`. So pick the primary key of `p`:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT p.NO_) AS COUNT
FROM `psttodo-in` p
INNER JOIN `deelgebied` d 
    ON d.`Segmentcode` = p.`Segment No_ PST`
    AND d.`Deelgebied` = p.`Deelgebied`
INNER JOIN m2m 
    ON m2m.`deelgebied` = d.`deelgebiedID`
WHERE 
    p.`Segment No_ PST` = 'PSS1400146'
    AND p.`Deelgebied` = 2
ORDER BY `afgewerkt tablet datum`
```

**Use a semi-join**

A [semi-join](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra#Semijoin_.28.E2.8B.89.29.28.E2.8B.8A.29) returns only one row of the result even if there are multiple matches. The way to write a semi-join in SQL is like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS COUNT
FROM `psttodo-in` p
INNER JOIN `deelgebied` d 
    ON d.`Segmentcode` = p.`Segment No_ PST`
    AND d.`Deelgebied` = p.`Deelgebied`
WHERE 
    p.`Segment No_ PST` = 'PSS1400146'
    AND p.`Deelgebied` = 2
    AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM m2m WHERE m2m.`deelgebied` = d.`deelgebiedID`)
ORDER BY `afgewerkt tablet datum`
```

Semi-join optimization was improved in MySQL 5.6, so I recommend upgrading if you use this solution.